# Why there are commands missing in bin/magento?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, exception, developer-mode, application

I need to set the application mode to *developer*, but when I tried doing so I got the exception

```
[InvalidArgumentException]
There are no commands defined in the "deploy:mode" namespace.
```

Running `bin/magento list`, I notice that many of the commands that I need to use, including all `deploy:` commands do not show.

**What can be the cause of this?**

I am using **Magento CE 2.1.3**.

Comment: try with, php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Comment: Wow, I thought I already tried that. This solved my problem.

Comment: above command is working for you?

Comment: Use `php bin/magento` instead of `bin/magento`

Comment: Yes, the above command works. Thank you @Rakesh

Comment: You can close this question after accept as solutions.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You have to run command

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Answer (score 10):

In my case I was setting up a new server and had copied the database over from a development site. Although I had an `app/etc/env.php` file and it was pointing at the correct db, it was missing the install/date timestamp config so Magento didn't know that the application had been installed and wasn't showing all the commands. Thanks to yaronishs answer I was able to figure this out, simply adding a timestamp to `app/etc/env.php` got all the expected commands running.

Comment: In my case it was missing `install` entry with timestamp in `app/etc/env.php`. After adding `install` all commands were added

Answer (score 8):

Some commands became available only after installation. 
The mentioned exception appears once you try to run such commands before installation.

**Probably you missed installing Magento.**

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to execute the command
`bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`. so after research i had found that install date is missing in env.php file.

I added below element in env.php,

> 'install' => [
> 'date' => 'Thu, 01 Feb 2021 05:48:29 +0000'
> ]

Answer (score 1):

I Was facing the same issue (Magento CE 2.4.3-p2)

**Re-executing php bin/magento setup:install Command fixed this issue**.

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://127.0.0.1/projects/m243/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento_243" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="Admin" --admin-lastname="User" --admin-email="admin@gmail.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin" --elasticsearch-host=127.0.0.1 --elasticsearch-port=9200 --search-engine=elasticsearch7
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue,

> [InvalidArgumentException] There are no commands defined in the
> "deploy:mode" namespace.

then I check for `env.php` inside `app/etc` folder,
it is was missing,
after adding `env.php` inside `app/etc` folder command is running properly

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but the solution was different, so I thought I'd log that here.

The problem was that I'd uploaded an invalid module (it was lacking a module.xml file).

Whilst running most commands returned "There are no commands defined in the "deploy:mode" namespace.", if I ran the command **php bin/magento** then it returned a more useful error message, which allowed me to find the fix.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, there was a permission issue.

please execute the permission command for var, generated (chmod command), and also check the file's owner (chown command)